# JavaScript client side (user input) find-and-replace Hyperlinks

Tags: replace, global

I want a clientside user to be able to insert text in text input box, click 'replace' and have a list of hyperlinks replaced accordingly. Anchor text will stay the same, but the hyperlink will change.

My problem: I am only getting the first hyperlink to change. I have a fiddle set up with two links, and you can see only the first changes. I want a list of, say, 20 links to change at once.

jsfiddle.net/TKxuf/

HTML:

```
<input id="replace" type="text" value="newphrase" />
<input onclick="doReplace()" type="button" value="Replace!" />

<br/>
<p id="list"><a href="google.com/q=keyword">Google Keyword Search</a></p>
<p id="list"><a href="yahoo.com/q=keyword">Yahoo Keyword Search</a></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
function doReplace() {
  var s = "keyword";
  var r = document.getElementById('replace').value;

  var oldtext = document.getElementById('list').innerHTML;
  var newtext = oldtext.replace( s, r );

  console.log(s);
  console.log(r);
  console.log(document.getElementById('list'));
  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = newtext;
}
```

Comment: Let me add: I the user to be able to repeat the find and replace as they wish without having to reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

I can't work out why you'd want the original strings in the HTML page code to begin with, so I'd suggest that you may have a problem with your approach. Note also that it's illegal in HTML to have more than one element with the same Id, which mostly explains why getElementById only returns one item. Also external urls must be preceded by http:// too.

I usually use jQuery these days - in jQuery you could simply swap id="list" to class="list" and use $('.list') to get a list of them all. $('.list').each(function() { var item = this; /* manipulation code here */ }); would allow you to change them all, but you may have to do some reading.

In any case, I still think that your approach is wrong.

What I'd do is have a normal javascript array of Urls, with replacable keys that are difficult to confuse as part of the url, e.g.

```
var addresses = [
    { text: "Google Keyword Search", url: "http://google.com?q=%keyword%" },
    { text: "Yahoo Keyword Search", url: "http://yahoo.com?q=%keyword%" }
];
```

When your user searches, you then build up your new html code into a string by iterating through the array:

```
var output = '';
for (var i = 0; i<addresses.length; i++) {
    var item = addresses[i];
    output += '<p><a href="'+escape(item.url.replace('%keyword%', r))+'">'+item.text+'</a></p>';
}
```

Note: I haven't checked this code, but you should be able to get the idea. You'd actually write out all the entire list by using innerHTML on the list container.

Hope that this helps.

Best Regards,
Mark Rabjohn
[Integrated Arts Limited](http://www.ia.uk.com)